# MJRecorder Audio Device

Tags: macos

I have been using Sound Source to control app specific volume on my iMac 2017. This app shows two separate audio devices - Headphones and MJRecorder Recorder Device. Any idea where this MJRecorder Device came from and which app installed this is an audio device?

I would want to remove this if it is not a default system audio device.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever install [Traktor Pro](https://www.native-instruments.com/forum/threads/what-is-mjrecorder-device.341841/).  It just a device driver for a Digital DJ Software.  There's really no harm in it being there, but if you don't use it, no harm in removing it, either.

Answer (score 2):

Someone on [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7981690) recommended you Delete "**MJRecorderDevice.driver**" located in **/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL** then reboot your system.

[image: MJRecorderDevices]

Comment: Why delete it?  The OP is asking to identify it and has not indicated there are any issues. It's for a legitimate product and for all you know, you could be breaking something he uses for work.

Comment: Quoted from his question "I would want to remove this if it is not a default system audio device." We were both answering two portions of his question -- you were answering the portion that asks what it might be, and I was answering the portion of how to remove it if it's not a default system audio device -- which it is not.

Comment: I've never installed Traktor Pro so I've no clue where this came from. Anyway, i take it this is not a default audio device and will delete it. Thank you both.